# Convert XML data to Json Data

Tags: jquery, json, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to convert XML data to json Data. with following Code

**CODE :**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "G:/A/B/C/test.xml",
    dataType: "xml"
}).done(function (xmlData) {
    var jsonData = $.xmlToJSON(xmlData);
    alert(jsonData);
    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
});
```

But gets following Error.

**ERROR:**

XMLHttpRequest cannot load "G:/A/B/C/test.xml". Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Anybody can help me about this?

Comment: i guess the Error explains it well…!

Comment: Is that a file on your computer? If so you can't do that, you'll need a webserver

Comment: To add to what adeneo says, requests made from the browser to the machines' local file system are blocked for security reasons. You can run a local server quite easily using IIS or XAMP for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross domain javascript to access localhost. Possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861257/cross-domain-javascript-to-access-localhost-possible)